# TemplateUrl, ngRoute this is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-route

I have a problem with my code:

```js
var app = angular.module( "myApp", ['ngRoute'] );

app.config( function ( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider
    .when( '/home', { templateUrl: 'strony/home.html' } )
    .when( '/about', { templateUrl: 'strony/about.html' } )
    .when( '/contact', { templateUrl: 'strony/contact.html' } )
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/this' } );
});

app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Path looks like: 
-index.html 
-script.js 
-strony/ 
        *home.html 
        *about.html
        *contact.html

If i click on link adress name is changing but on site nothing happenes. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Any errors and are you referencing angular-route? please provide more information. Maybe provide a plunk or codepen?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/a9RcN5xHVyz75EnRiWBT?p=preview
that is look like but here i delete folder 'strony'

Comment: See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a forward slash in front of "strony" (`i.e.'/strony/home.html'`) and make sure your are referencing your module (i.e. `<html ng-app='myApp'>`)

Your code will reflect the following:

**HTML**

```
 <html ng-app='myApp'>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module( "myApp", ['ngRoute'] );

app.config( function ( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider
    .when( '/home', { templateUrl: '/strony/home.html' } )
    .when( '/about', { templateUrl: '/strony/about.html' } )
    .when( '/contact', { templateUrl: '/strony/contact.html' } )
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/this' } );
});

app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
});
```

Here's a working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1LHs3gOYildY2Xk8cUcX?p=preview)

**Also, ng-route needs a web server to work. Maybe use something like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)**.

Comment: still doesn`t work. in head i have scripts angular.min.js and angular-route.min.js

Comment: still nothing. I have ng-app='myApp' in HTML and i change 'strony/home.html' to '/strony/home.html'. One more information, when i click on link in adress page is changing but on site is nothing happenes

Comment: Yes now in your Plunk it is working but if in my code in sublime still doesn`t work and i don`t know why ;/ have you any idea? mabye i must enter localhost? And okay i try to use local server thanks for help :)

Comment: I had to strat it by localhost. Now everything is working ;)